# How do I make a range slider fluid?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a slider with 3 values and am trying to add a smoothing/fluid effect when pulling the tab from one value to another.

Here is what I thought would work:

HTML

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="3" value="1" class="slider">
```

CSS

```
.slider {
  display: inherit;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.05s
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.05s
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pcoledesign/5f1k4xLt/6/

Comment: You're going to need a custom JS solution for that. HTML inputs do not have many options for styling and definitely won't accept CSS transitions.

Comment: What framework are you using? jQuery? Angular? I want to give an appropriate answer. I can share with you also in Javascript.

Comment: I'm using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is try to put `step` attribute to the `input` element. and use `Math.round()` to get the value if you only want the values of  1,2,3